# Get (and sum) values of all attributes named 'test' in XML

Tags: python, xml

Example XML doc:

```
<main>
  <this test="500">
    <that test="200"/>
  </this>
</main>
```

Result: 700

All the existing code snippets I've found on this site and others rely on a tag. For example, you could only get "500" if you reference both "this" and "test". I'm looking to search only for "test" throughout the entire doc/string.

Some modules that I've tried (and resulted in failure) are lxml, xml.dom, ElementTree, xmltodict, and BeautifulSoup,

Comment: Show the code that failed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the code since I usually only save what works/outputs something other than an error. I only got KeyErrors and AttributeErrors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to favor [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) for parsing XML in python. `lxml` has full [xpath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) support, and xpath is the language/technology designed specifically for querying XML.

Once you have the right tool for the right job, you can do something like this f.e :

```
import lxml.etree as et

xml = """<main>
  <this test="500">
    <that test="200"/>
  </this>
</main>"""
doc = et.fromstring(xml)
result = doc.xpath("sum(//@test)")
print(result)
```

**output :**

```
700.0
```

**brief explanation about xpath being used :**

- `//@test` : find all `test` attribute anywhere in the XML document.
- `sum()` : return sum of the parameter

Comment: Wow, I was so close to getting this. Thank you!